# ubuntu 22.04 is ignoring/deleting my autostart applications

Tags: 22.04, startup, autostart

Been using ubuntu since version... 16? and never had this issue before. Just started after transitioning from 20 to 22.

PROBLEM:

I add an application to the list of startup applications (then close and re-open the Startup Applications Preferences dialog box to verify that my new entry is still there), reboot, and find that

a) the application has in fact not auto-launched, and


b) when I re-open the Startup Applications Preferences dialog box, my application is no longer in the list.

Any insight?

Comment: I've been using 22.04 since it was released and not experienced any issue such as you mention. Have you installed Tweaks?

Comment: I have tweaks. Always one of my first installs. Adding an app to autostart via tweaks has the same problem.

Comment: That does not happen by the default system. You will need to provide details on which application you attempt to autostart. The application may be managing that.